# programming late binding

Tags: programming-languages, late-binding

I have a situation which is very similar to late binding in programming languages, i work for a javaee based enterprise software shop. All the happenings in the programming universe makes me think there could be a dynamic language which is better suited than java for the problem at hand.

Scenario - We are writing UI for a firewall configuration app. The firewall rules have to be defined at a higher level of abstraction, in terms of abstract objects that can represent a class/family of actual devices etc. This is the design phase.

There is a deploy phase where the abstract objects are resolved to produce actual CLI s to be pushed to the hardware. Here "resolution" involves the abstract objects mapped to real values like ip/port/zone based on a list of runtime contexts that are available at the time of deploy.

This process sounds very similar to the late binding in the compilation/interpretation phase of languages and makes me wonder there must be another language that has implicit support to model this more accurately. Request all to please throw some light.

Comment: Actually, I think that's more like compilation, which is eminently amenable to early-bound and functional approaches. There's no reason you can't do that in java. I'd recommend anything else, because I think java is a pain, but that's more a matter of taste than anything else.